# Android google maps to show current location

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a simple verison of google maps whuch indicates the current position using GPS.I have tried many links and not sure most of them just display the map.Any links for this which has worked for you....

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/GPSLocator.aspx

even in the above link could get the longitude and the latitude working

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a simple verison of google maps whuch indicates the current position using GPS.

Use `MyLocationOverlay`, as that is what it is there for. [Here is a sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk) that uses `MyLocationOverlay` and a custom overlay; you can always get rid of the custom one if you do not need it.